# Multiple Calls to Visit with RSpec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a requests spec that makes multiple calls to visit within a single block (visits '/sessions/new' and visits '/admin'). This results in:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `view_factory' for #<#<Class:0x007fedda1d5180>:0x007fedda1bb118>
```

Any way to fix this? Thanks. The code is:

```
describe "Admin" do

  before do
    visit new_session_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Submit"
  end

  describe "GET /admin" do
    it "should be successful" do
      visit admin_dashboard_path
    end
  end

end
```

**Update**:

After some searching, I found that the errors only occure when running with [Spork](https://github.com/timcharper/spork). Here is my `spec_helper.rb` flile that configures Spork:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
require 'simplecov'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

SimpleCov.start if ENV["COVERAGE"]

Spork.prefork do

  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :mocha

    config.include Auth::Helper
  end

end
```

Comment: it works with just one call to visit? I would guess that something is setup wrong but then you wouldn't get the first visit to run either....

Comment: @froderik Yeah, that's what I think as well. I just realized that it only fails when running with Spork (https://github.com/timcharper/spork).

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same issue: error only happens when using spork and seems related to ActiveAdmin

Comment: @hubble None that I'm aware of.

Comment: Suuuuxxxx... I'm stuck running rspec without spork / guard : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found a little workaround. I assume that `view_factory` is a helper method defined in a plugin and it is included to the application helper with something like `ActionController::Base.helper FactoryHelperModule`.

What I did was to include the following snippet to my app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  include FactoryHelperModule
end
```

**If** the helper methods are in a module and **if** the helper methods are declared like mine, there is a chance that this will work. I haven't found yet why this happens though.

Btw, I am on rails `3.0.4` and spork `0.9.0.rc9`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will fix your issue, but `before` needs to be inside the block passed to `describe`:

```
describe "GET /admin" do
  before do
    visit new_session_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Submit"
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    visit admin_dashboard_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry the code I pasted was just a snippet from the full spec. It contains a describe around everything (and thus the before is allowed where it is). I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

See my solution here: http://railsgotchas.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/activeadmin-spork-and-the-infamous-undefined-local-variable-or-method-view_factory/